# Todoist api get all completed tasks?

Tags: javascript, api, todoist

Im using todoists rest api to track my own data but it seems like it only allows you to fetch active tasks?

I was looking at filters and thinking they may help me but there is no documentation on this.

Im trying to fetch all tasks completed on a certain day, Can this be done?

Answer (score 5):

Completed tasks are not implemented in the REST API yet. To be able to retrieve completed tasks, you should be using the Sync API: https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v8/#get-all-completed-items

Comment: Thats a shame, Thanks